# MIPS what hex word encodes branch instruction?

Tags: assembly, branch, mips

To my understanding the branch in this instruction is the first line, which can be represented as the hexadecimal value "10b8ffff". However apparently this is not the correct answer.

- Is the encoding of the branch instruction also reliant on the rest of the MIPS code?

or

- Am I just just getting the incorrect hex value when I translate the first line?

Here is the MIPS code:

```
    beq  $5, $24, L1
    slli $8, $7, 2
    add  $8, $8, $15
    lw   $8, 0($8)
    sw   $8, 0($23)
 L1: addi $7, $7, 1
```

Comment: it is reliant, for it's jumping relative to PC+4 ... if you want to branch to skip 4 instructions, offset is 4, if you want to jump back also count the BEQ itself, -1 will land on the Branch itself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first portion, `0x10b8` appears to be correct. I believe that the problem is how you are arriving at 0xFFFF for the offset. Note this from an instruction reference, where `beq $s, $t, offset`:

> if $s == $t advance_pc (offset << 2)); else advance_pc (4);

You are saying that `L1`, which is only 5 instructions away, is at an offset of 0xFFFF, which will then be left shifted twice to determine the correct location. Since this looks "assignmentish", I will leave it to you to figure out the correct value based on instruction sizes.

Comment: Thanks, I can see how that makes sense :)

Comment: From the actual assembler hex output, the hex for the `beq` inst is `10b80004`. The `L1` label is at addr/offset 0x14 (as you mentioned, 5 insts away). Thus, the `beq` always adds 4 (bytes) first, regardless, then applies the offset (doing the shift) if the branch is taken. So, it's more like: `advance_pc(4); if $s == $t advance_pc(offset << 2)`.

Comment: btw: offsett FFFF for BEQ (like in "10b8ffff") would be an endless loop